# How to select all elements by data-attribute with specific value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a truble with jQuery. How to write a selector that selects only elements, witch have an data-attribute and specific value.

I'm trying:

```
$('form').find('*[data-root!=0]')
```

it's returns all elements - with/without data-root.

```
$('form').find('*[data-root]').find('*[data-root!="0"]')
```

and this code return nothing

Comment: Post an HTML sample please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `*`. There's also no need for `find`. You need to add `[data-root]` on its own. This finds all descendant elements of `form` elements that have `data-root` with a value that isn't `0`:

```
$('form [data-root][data-root!=0]')
```

although I think I'd be more comfortable putting the `0` in quotes:

```
$('form [data-root][data-root!="0"]')
```

That's because `0` isn't a valid [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), and the value of an attribute must be a valid CSS identifier or a [string](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings) (e.g., in quotes) (more [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors)).

Selector explanation:

```
form [data-root][data-root!="0"]
/^^\^/^^^^^^^^^\/^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\
 |  |     |            |
 |  |     |            +−−− the attribute can't be equal to "0"
 |  |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− must have the attribute
 |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− is a descendant...
 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− ...of a `form`
```

Live Example:

```js
$('form [data-root][data-root!="0"]').each(function(i) {
    console.log(i + ": " + $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div data-root="0">no match (value is 0)</div>
  <div>no match (no attribute)</div>
  <div data-root="1">match (value is "1")</div>
</form>
<form>
  <div data-root="0">no match again (value is 0)</div>
  <div>no match again (no attribute)</div>
  <div data-root="">match (value is "")</div>
  <div data-root="2">match (value is "2")</div>
</form>
<div data-root="3">no match (not in a <code>form</code>)</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @DanilPyatnitsev - Ah! Silly me. Fixed. Adding `[data-root]` tells the selector engine we only want ones that have the attribute. Combined with `[data-root!="0"]`, we get only the ones that have it, but don't have it with the value `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a filter function

```
$('form').find('[data-root]').filter("[data-root!='0']");
```

Comment: Fairly inefficient given that filtering is what CSS selectors **do**, but yes, it's possible. (And it's not often that the efficiency matters.)